# Extracting amount of cells with a specific difference depending on multiple criteria

Tags: r

I have two datasets that i need to compare but i'm having issues. I want to test how many nests there are within 500 meter (and 200 meter) of an experiment. This is easily down, however i need to make sure that if multiple nests that are within 500 meter of a trial are within 100 meter of another, that only one of them is counted. I have two seperate data sets:

In one dataset i have experiment per row and the distance of each nest to that experiment per column(more than 300 and the last columns contain random text).
[image]

```
structure(list(Trial = c("Trial001", "Trial002", "Trial004"), 
    lat1 = c(51.986605, 51.964813, 51.978067), lon1 = c("5.6420649999999997", 
    "5.6531940000000001", "5.6698880000000003"), `1` = c("1.2720590919577208", 
    "1.6043508641207493", "0.95013388668046761"), `2` = c(1.38432188843301, 
    1.496982341898, 0.895672914471978), `3` = c(1.53379591394998, 
    1.03484535956492, 1.34691079840422), `4` = c(1.20518179921142, 
    1.33712816324608, 1.50659842826192), `5` = c(1.15102958435049, 
    1.41807692980155, 1.38488502848898), `6` = c(1.14207543583242, 
    1.45028047066378, 1.3272278290973), `7` = c("1.2259199316564593", 
    "1.4543602646696516", "1.1545983962837512"), `8` = c("1.6154201419825798", 
    "1.3954443952558941", "0.73183486429186906"), `9` = c("1.8101354251702091", 
    "1.0113448881468761", "0.97906331948980174"), `10` = c(1.68429072965108, 
    1.12076159174288, 0.958525960853523), `11` = c(1.66006322996026, 
    0.96310588607099, 1.2278194355031), `12` = c(1.34814338139164, 
    1.23520481643555, 1.30676074303396), `13` = c(0.889316816329877, 
    1.65587946051563, 1.57254520949305), `14` = c(1.00979279191042, 
    1.53822624549759, 1.69726526300676), `15` = c(0.877437909031816, 
    1.66305099416402, 1.66212657792635), `16` = c(0.765227305026136, 
    1.77754711056468, 1.73835544290527), `17` = c(0.69127824177588, 
    1.8578724653621, 1.64217890122481), `18` = c("0.69713023629362803", 
    "1.8862517250410173", "1.5540658187749201"), `19` = c("0.89381991485358792", 
    "1.8871490573357999", "1.2602034952163557"), `20` = c(0.844995148336332, 
    1.98511721731381, 1.28874983309535), `21` = c(0.407265191951536, 
    2.13700695766427, 1.82863201016005), `22` = c(0.379650244880847, 
    2.1737870547174, 1.96705698995751), `23` = c(0.128467418972502, 
    2.42416891655658, 2.09019161165919), `24` = c("0.23576439169194296", 
    "2.56913726535719", "1.9800526111919627"), `25` = c(0.32551277306911, 
    2.47020219172597, 1.84750875360012), `26` = c(0.270415759824767, 
    2.27194663366827, 1.92711056890678), `27` = c(0.531955268091355, 
    2.18586656642318, 1.59759133841377), `28` = c(0.382150506575062, 
    2.18760087139323, 1.79022646796125), `29` = c(0.51566990782668, 
    2.3018000958435, 1.6259135638876), `30` = c(0.625470877586691, 
    2.37595510250346, 1.56533854490626), `31` = c(0.422687471231421, 
    2.47137473602335, 1.774671707685), `32` = c("0.56329391667987183", 
    "2.5477685531885985", "1.7229236346154095"), `33` = c(0.66184423359023, 
    2.1494266342535, 1.4673511496305), `34` = c(2.50080414490285, 
    0.0455149165459399, 1.82445873029136), `35` = c(2.74071175396326, 
    0.257644534192079, 2.1157797892021), `36` = c(2.67775666626278, 
    0.174037142759214, 2.03306322472445), `37` = c(2.63507385492696, 
    0.199636494402726, 2.06314660347644), `38` = c(2.59135781518709, 
    0.102738942614632, 1.96764109508823), `39` = c(2.66105262768166, 
    0.308912165787341, 2.16541727001792), `40` = c("1.8676339583685737", 
    "1.257643257045403", "0.67067053877478333"), `41` = c(2.20027904846844, 
    1.06019873022796, 0.811838111759701), `42` = c(1.7792032167898, 
    1.36326421078349, 0.622456586133017), `43` = c("2.2426493618266443", 
    "0.87124849371316571", "1.0008686790185393"), `44` = c("2.4005136243213441", 
    "1.2621554734744178", "0.70809156729560896"), `45` = c(2.29673208900843, 
    1.34607641085479, 0.573610179177611), `46` = c(2.46628258420254, 
    1.38942541261708, 0.648358162510136), `47` = c("2.0481780255520885", 
    "0.50288922782216772", "1.7227377913091932"), `48` = c(2.53899715670466, 
    1.23372222001448, 0.833105355634421), `49` = c(2.30811905939469, 
    1.48911893686832, 0.450394765768018), `50` = c(2.51641658494524, 
    1.49134900882124, 0.612345911398691), `51` = c(2.23718969790818, 
    1.75492497638455, 0.1731055283873), `52` = c("2.1720949583572118", 
    "1.7201965143497018", "0.16139673564343715"), `53` = c(2.01614332514864, 
    1.39257762262327, 0.480155473991488), `54` = c("1.7790157497555334", 
    "1.5724072828431037", "0.44909525773017411"), `55` = c(1.87904836633097, 
    1.60055465743963, 0.351478667920529), `56` = c(2.11001767370161, 
    1.77572448300929, 0.0897501657496114), `57` = c(1.86170672461784, 
    1.4593529936335, 0.480035994909118), `58` = c(1.70760314400997, 
    1.61689267697744, 0.484382442063476), `59` = c(1.69810984520388, 
    1.75104315931595, 0.439843001623716), `60` = c(1.64062990403534, 
    1.83644403638498, 0.488267586082819), `61` = c(1.5390278389966, 
    1.6749371308105, 0.623105931836954), `62` = c(1.94051713672313, 
    1.71953848860316, 0.225573779568672), `63` = c(1.69815725109506, 
    1.90487129365581, 0.438753789079568), `64` = c(1.76885609398657, 
    1.7679268970639, 0.366236509660607), `65` = c(1.85844093854363, 
    1.73278764507677, 0.290409466169061), `66` = c("1.9043907970810174", 
    "1.8030332216178595", "0.22697229039419753"), `67` = c(1.78804146480642, 
    1.86275331134467, 0.342792260354445), `68` = c(1.89666638930128, 
    1.95110138932599, 0.263568702087665), `69` = c(2.12023226425867, 
    2.05561187446237, 0.197555359617742), `70` = c("2.001133551646797", 
    "1.9125213231802769", "0.14605313503145045"), `71` = c(2.12566379519772, 
    1.90247709090114, 0.0386415818650094), `72` = c(2.21222579074705, 
    2.12358306162903, 0.258776104271554), `73` = c(2.32610828317803, 
    2.13954950122156, 0.301609098021851), `74` = c(2.52797972264317, 
    2.31468470132712, 0.521277445761215), `75` = c(2.72502026359007, 
    2.31589771414459, 0.646995694614279), `76` = c(2.54513836669434, 
    2.16715733295158, 0.452805047730659), `77` = c(2.46359261857469, 
    2.01368780644111, 0.339160281617408), `78` = c(2.37201264486237, 
    1.93000295410315, 0.243137990776232), `79` = c(2.31045716411468, 
    2.41465811211233, 0.549323444649631), `80` = c(2.5829554375447, 
    2.10062009644109, 0.464094736230751), `81` = c("2.7685335948991554", 
    "2.0899013462920255", "0.63965498158051637"), `82` = c(2.78954699689177, 
    2.02106563136212, 0.665076261719375), `83` = c(2.92656701773526, 
    2.17197870175113, 0.797693727283156), `84` = c(2.8837227257435, 
    1.95405977210953, 0.778731178101442), `85` = c("3.0123369541499896", 
    "1.9495230102438021", "0.92332272404346782"), `86` = c("2.8459306563141724", 
    "1.7740992455096405", "0.79747677299331454"), `87` = c(2.75450878013287, 
    1.8549707499475, 0.664418972091045), `88` = c(2.75851245848153, 
    1.56857570072887, 0.806473607801987), `89` = c(2.63577843066273, 
    1.67019736832873, 0.615831089639475), `90` = c(2.64611378113837, 
    1.5257686581209, 0.714450860421761), `91` = c("3.5445913798041824", 
    "2.1848711000721015", "1.4708957276675114"), `92` = c(3.57799280916631, 
    2.29084644449727, 1.48213089982194), `93` = c(3.60256204059138, 
    2.49133704357849, 1.47795412156297), `94` = c("3.9073646519816361", 
    "3.0013152396648342", "1.7905282495965498"), `95` = c("4.045403831299752", 
    "2.8536308630980813", "1.918320619676313"), `96` = c(3.12124429019916, 
    2.18140955805654, 0.997344471572444), `97` = c(3.19444907575354, 
    2.4640429838338, 1.07564413385325), `98` = c(3.43383510641478, 
    2.70736163032242, 1.32791997355056), `99` = c(1.35573162476881, 
    1.29133352265244, 1.91291048227297), `100` = c(2.91217457683244, 
    1.99708473228378, 3.55741325144498), `101` = c(2.83694569817315, 
    1.87820856000765, 3.44062946448777), `102` = c(2.70288253339591, 
    1.66727175724563, 3.22967238315615), `103` = c("2.578218739305381", 
    "1.4557807663072349", "3.0171188770559443"), `104` = c("2.6050950094964165", 
    "0.91205138792790241", "1.1502932069937564"), `105` = c(3.84374687860946, 
    2.40524251456255, 1.76432411778257), `106` = c(4.04673519150528, 
    2.402784369488, 2.01540836772321), `107` = c(4.15655036848612, 
    2.69711552783705, 2.06226295611937), `108` = c(3.15314069950444, 
    1.55557362015348, 1.27355680849202), `109` = c(2.97440993756312, 
    1.48174405758583, 1.10331269101189), `110` = c(2.82254131599297, 
    1.2151209724399, 1.1165369386658), `111` = c(3.14968013758263, 
    1.40488876952267, 1.36634397586768), `112` = c(3.06602392660123, 
    1.29377940625719, 1.33991276216192), `113` = c(2.90951256314749, 
    1.21008696327159, 1.21585679971995), `114` = c(2.17442465846338, 
    0.609409946868215, 2.0854602367391), `115` = c(3.23471291967592, 
    0.849527112752085, 2.69523549038475), `116` = c(2.85583229296164, 
    0.494056334136652, 1.76118818337827), `117` = c(2.73018328541294, 
    0.501037528250883, 1.60523895424205), `118` = c(2.87842195193562, 
    0.828170062561606, 1.48409531130341), `119` = c(2.88809654776556, 
    2.30571730746416, 0.775959441206657), `120` = c(3.21340464374408, 
    2.79522046766794, 1.1878581668297), `121` = c(3.64171365946613, 
    3.00106097461679, 1.56907360668929), `122` = c(3.55402289540828, 
    3.11092001294428, 1.5467142210701), `123` = c(3.47750234835772, 
    3.10466398251004, 1.49597782531404), `124` = c(3.34502416949462, 
    3.33619579522735, 1.56902449498237), `125` = c(2.93415207974717, 
    3.0023960709156, 1.18418907108157), `126` = c(2.87493909684235, 
    2.74689230519525, 0.973687453644284), `127` = c(2.90566927738533, 
    2.67514733775314, 0.942539154172745), `128` = c(2.70232250260775, 
    2.72193805662428, 0.89296471382289), `129` = c(2.26443228572905, 
    2.70657236257614, 0.857469685980893), `130` = c(2.36877200508027, 
    2.74241063262811, 0.881075295978167), `131` = c(2.37747956943678, 
    3.03389774361118, 1.19247540552433), `132` = c(2.29152572192305, 
    2.92792028975051, 1.09349003816443), `133` = c(2.54002145758648, 
    3.00390793445632, 1.14020591587694), `134` = c(2.68257790343232, 
    3.27245424130061, 1.409916992508), `135` = c(2.79893042095679, 
    3.67188552049297, 1.82515475071954), `136` = c(2.71031147999416, 
    3.68101895383791, 1.85074661328135), `137` = c(2.45829316800845, 
    3.50099056450777, 1.70321727671849), `138` = c(1.50703337011332, 
    1.87405476527171, 0.622700803342536), `139` = c(1.97001399862872, 
    2.60717123700537, 0.840445598695845), `140` = c(2.00932587528267, 
    2.90343957071244, 1.15667491951317), `141` = c(2.45623924440529, 
    3.30285339702587, 1.47582000228617), `142` = c(2.27829842056722, 
    3.30620790956548, 1.52866147548743), `143` = c(2.40480649866084, 
    3.57858890319705, 1.81169092394619), `144` = c(2.23526561552069, 
    3.42916704218212, 1.69067779167765), `145` = c(2.21320828965057, 
    3.526417747064, 1.81863041981105), `146` = c(2.48802844309624, 
    3.96925728456638, 2.26693747968054), `147` = c(2.58023189962712, 
    4.24878665363572, 2.59550697100963), `148` = c(2.22277459191776, 
    3.95496424729124, 2.37261454750812), `149` = c(2.34569807394837, 
    3.96880029527322, 2.32921414255542), `150` = c(2.22857434222239, 
    3.82380185813813, 2.19256400713319), `151` = c(2.10771127788384, 
    3.80362267575947, 2.22717451811716), `152` = c(2.03911801405834, 
    3.65686256676098, 2.06661853209444), `153` = c(2.13775526301201, 
    4.14744948665336, 2.70279296774684), `154` = c(2.44900614588572, 
    4.28398820946416, 2.71152745251738), `155` = c(2.32077179045246, 
    4.32803069702034, 2.85555827383681), `156` = c(1.70273715424122, 
    3.48511835020512, 2.0287169435774), `157` = c(1.46108725922971, 
    3.14089170768357, 1.73127069139861), `158` = c(1.14092495144833, 
    2.98642541537048, 1.75621442310229), `159` = c(2.72009730598436, 
    4.46617670484977, 2.826855322426), `160` = c(2.9587761525173, 
    4.64788767578693, 2.96593166252078), `161` = c(2.98372157500467, 
    4.78619250057135, 3.14566287211339), `162` = c(2.89360445638967, 
    4.6595398648563, 3.01185385282538), `163` = c(2.718878556348, 
    4.59836818663931, 3.01547470167942), `164` = c(2.6060644023312, 
    4.59371579330106, 3.07618291440115), `165` = c(2.4483894627168, 
    4.50445341637266, 3.04322407684284), `166` = c(2.49972290839981, 
    4.6291153344627, 3.20758396879812), `167` = c(2.8275904300713, 
    4.83393032380102, 3.30427704444469), `168` = c(2.77397677925063, 
    4.72390825026149, 3.16956584862251), `169` = c(0.297764074027341, 
    2.8238490488134, 2.39731038971236), `170` = c(0.145013162669556, 
    2.68139399261135, 2.25259374204375), `171` = c(1.77300136990854, 
    0.860282545310304, 1.87562185273582), `172` = c(1.86586469993455, 
    0.790445943151856, 1.91790628973325), `173` = c(1.85074754827618, 
    0.727742061908479, 1.76899590384464), `174` = c(1.82730870284345, 
    0.729040655019664, 1.44560246989271), `175` = c(1.98939553712977, 
    0.563960786536853, 1.51413715122957), `176` = c(2.49152379260061, 
    0.160258319126319, 1.71137249271106), `177` = c(2.20527082886817, 
    0.77465677343916, 1.09093640302993), `178` = c(2.38558712081918, 
    0.627937470553333, 1.26333401478231), `179` = c(2.36259595131829, 
    0.510506335832342, 1.36329414563028), `180` = c(1.1507955688831, 
    2.17486686093394, 1.03602617191466), `181` = c(1.17432934557782, 
    2.19970539557974, 1.02766934396518), `182` = c(1.02295478385493, 
    2.11720927528302, 1.12714352191834), `183` = c(1.02207699030799, 
    2.35334855447901, 1.2391528112649), `184` = c(0.981443618336508, 
    2.34802378112516, 1.2678989972662), `185` = c(0.862568398954724, 
    2.28121057701135, 1.32739926101953), `186` = c(1.11085826310077, 
    2.38471513109725, 1.19096160822594), `187` = c(1.33776575948877, 
    2.43400927467, 1.05748069715842), `188` = c(1.17329790585098, 
    2.57132054217685, 1.29588415808621), `189` = c(1.4306204096391, 
    2.25095182423033, 0.846456629168543), `190` = c(1.48146030603904, 
    2.17657784586776, 0.756354720683537), `191` = c(1.38279056829579, 
    2.10783619942835, 0.803856281878769), `192` = c(7.06357035848904, 
    9.58129485960558, 8.46728878399699), `193` = c(7.44979144169524, 
    9.96893973896226, 8.85442212936535), `194` = c(7.25409115802867, 
    9.76886349969295, 8.64016809263306), `195` = c(7.3027698534087, 
    9.72306083350881, 8.38078308875552), `196` = c(7.24974125220304, 
    9.65898986455813, 8.30098232724131), `197` = c(7.15111419197534, 
    9.55673268220617, 8.19515502495017), `198` = c(7.38715196593398, 
    9.8012313334202, 8.44807983551545), `199` = c(7.46082182075384, 
    9.87306120546585, 8.51595739672547), `200` = c(7.28683449971812, 
    9.71989760553652, 8.39835844818697), `201` = c(7.16904314987504, 
    9.5972065939703, 8.269668485949), `202` = c(7.35193328308328, 
    9.78780343335061, 8.46986860122471), `203` = c(6.92530903434479, 
    9.40199995305107, 8.17070623810773), `204` = c(6.84933488528005, 
    9.33629028953849, 8.13077564449049), `205` = c(6.83702814136785, 
    9.32830920719055, 8.13409164850937), `206` = c(6.97348473470634, 
    9.46640970856148, 8.27404526688886), `207` = c(7.06936274211282, 
    9.55527428675122, 8.34317609554618), `208` = c(7.05044449745669, 
    9.52598066856013, 8.2898267663051), `209` = c(7.19268716358475, 
    9.64965565134268, 8.37246315692579), `210` = c(7.24207432125561, 
    9.70825968403537, 8.44864734479385), `211` = c(7.27859794903541, 
    9.73181342670531, 8.44599373166693), `212` = c(7.35910570541382, 
    9.82471197533252, 8.56193618205825), `213` = c(7.3161151676878, 
    9.79969064420866, 8.57765142245363), `214` = c(7.20450866699249, 
    9.68552689430728, 8.45926930585157), `215` = c(7.27695484622098, 
    9.78113625587062, 8.61593207510156), `216` = c(7.35301333544825, 
    9.85107687278225, 8.6663902622185), `217` = c(7.26092656985521, 
    9.75698628666003, 8.56817812691283), `218` = c(7.0255168165846, 
    9.53475839781096, 8.3902456509825), `219` = c(6.88122479102114, 
    9.38188383753426, 8.21289901111141), `220` = c(6.81552508733487, 
    9.32284581987807, 8.17573275895542), `221` = c(5.20941676565384, 
    7.33946104050126, 5.76174697821608), `222` = c(5.29061508556606, 
    7.39269022184638, 5.79483047694619), `223` = c(5.1023766601576, 
    7.196093373912, 5.59846958592122), `224` = c(7.48779083419625, 
    10.001274566793, 8.8640326345639), `225` = c(7.43387597096703, 
    9.93097928888509, 8.74225578484575), `226` = c(5.71409911273721, 
    8.1415123332231, 6.84370377839804), `227` = c(5.72763837574716, 
    8.15417209723819, 6.85460436885732), `228` = c(5.66200517693311, 
    8.05064533951803, 6.69753537322016), `229` = c(5.70513928519987, 
    8.13727593306279, 6.84738110162083), `230` = c(5.52268937199826, 
    7.9501167784867, 6.65744334146983), `231` = c(5.33078748621769, 
    7.76089830734661, 6.47799713903708), `232` = c(5.34925856373785, 
    7.79656611372668, 6.54252294475245), `233` = c(5.19416845208734, 
    7.62059450712544, 6.33584055461135), `234` = c(5.3147399562246, 
    7.70964068060585, 6.37472149706691), `235` = c(5.49545258601624, 
    7.87465531280183, 6.51369508657736), `236` = c(5.2315467493021, 
    7.56387792964311, 6.15522827197961), `237` = c(5.39744025562816, 
    7.70716175933163, 6.26985807530733), `238` = c(6.06345927397778, 
    8.42870424779145, 7.03575039929568), `239` = c(6.0480178088873, 
    8.43211289661223, 7.06334549740219), `240` = c(6.0040599545546, 
    8.40755678108627, 7.06636566939432), `241` = c(6.00253512668279, 
    8.4097532219794, 7.07395458017892), `242` = c(6.00657640083095, 
    8.4177013988509, 7.08753112046382), `243` = c(5.91536355656582, 
    8.33854844842113, 7.02895691857494), `244` = c(5.82254196427621, 
    8.22685754843531, 6.89128639387791), `245` = c(5.95449347749989, 
    8.3261882531754, 6.94378356227186), `246` = c(1.15911945300366, 
    3.68647578346183, 2.9340970320505), `247` = c(1.17340551516494, 
    3.70800236765976, 2.98765899127825), `248` = c(1.22846640385594, 
    3.76849179497081, 3.09604245612914), `249` = c(1.25395543584791, 
    3.78569230357433, 3.21203727735148), `250` = c(1.25776520089835, 
    3.79738409106585, 3.15829636441884), `251` = c(2.0685216665923, 
    4.60234815958089, 3.77053569447179), `252` = c(2.38253522260673, 
    4.91482992339067, 4.04648115298028), `253` = c(2.78475303430566, 
    5.31589741916439, 4.41154838496242), `254` = c(2.54547551297749, 
    5.07557221157141, 4.41081918870335), `255` = c(2.22115688067105, 
    4.75834249652124, 4.06192663841314), `256` = c(2.43875653266869, 
    4.94673181222889, 4.38036479224729), `257` = c(1.74831606005632, 
    4.13168809260167, 3.84686917901322), `258` = c(1.22447286208091, 
    3.71331004579261, 2.85072142869066), `259` = c(1.28332127209844, 
    3.73662845848755, 2.80482064690994), `260` = c(4.89899771154443, 
    7.02307197439427, 5.45096160179294), `261` = c(4.65675487028939, 
    6.81791548250852, 5.27936654082639), `262` = c(4.68676875133948, 
    6.87244890578989, 5.35062956316251), `263` = c(6.31655101099404, 
    8.77931922498922, 7.53050249998104), `264` = c(6.29497635621219, 
    8.7522897468389, 7.49318797748454), `265` = c(5.74453704351385, 
    8.10095045847244, 6.70523831351215), `266` = c(5.67127383313457, 
    8.01986057641263, 6.61694512456785), `267` = c(5.92708321341038, 
    8.37011014680191, 7.09316319391981), `268` = c(6.13370260610207, 
    8.57060970130218, 7.27823072790217), `269` = c(6.36059219529611, 
    8.81082973642242, 7.53696148994999), `270` = c(6.42457115135884, 
    8.85636653753766, 7.54904478478745), `271` = c(6.51872806726111, 
    8.93514144582504, 7.60153868729811), `272` = c(6.43165094362951, 
    8.8739573512826, 7.58433493393763), `273` = c(6.47944957064647, 
    8.87263047146381, 7.50645188309315), `274` = c(6.49694639817532, 
    8.89135230444198, 7.52648360386613), `275` = c(6.464265024145, 
    8.87216932513949, 7.52704541866883), `276` = c(6.23398238167346, 
    8.63333556707092, 7.28097911563315), `277` = c(6.38906033476402, 
    8.81045200894685, 7.48722703927368), `278` = c(6.27683968204698, 
    8.71260680101465, 7.41508755347914), `279` = c(6.4150334433207, 
    8.87380794686976, 7.61497174632343), `280` = c(6.71862929394208, 
    9.15056786950502, 7.83750359648191), `281` = c(6.81016766496012, 
    9.24318490969651, 7.93013686381517), `282` = c(7.00124064800366, 
    9.43312832809837, 8.11465353367611), `283` = c(6.93162087370247, 
    9.37456769267482, 8.07620243538313), `284` = c(6.75068355713103, 
    9.18886376468682, 7.8856544724371), `285` = c(6.97793747561029, 
    9.39641685102568, 8.05704885785198), `286` = c(6.84976962642569, 
    9.26660058297447, 7.92709613833111), `287` = c(6.7924951295995, 
    9.2036794623759, 7.85679331695828), `288` = c(6.82953014784612, 
    9.25441714744896, 7.92781132616109), `289` = c(6.69348667642067, 
    9.12173561468316, 7.80314254345662), `290` = c(6.70213373231143, 
    9.12745981446474, 7.80401202864227), `291` = c(6.72948123972997, 
    9.13575727385905, 7.78291188364127), `292` = c(6.61718563916452, 
    9.01579132403474, 7.65427528779722), `293` = c(6.63586148178324, 
    9.04316566114606, 7.69365801570635), `294` = c(6.17466015137788, 
    8.6532545669592, 7.44149231605145), `295` = c(6.19866723848954, 
    8.67363406310792, 7.45315421124166), `296` = c(6.20855562101565, 
    8.69849998228063, 7.5135219144509), `297` = c(6.48919384055782, 
    8.98235241735821, 7.79987544018555), `298` = c(6.53587808352953, 
    9.03299779144343, 7.8604342449267), `299` = c(6.57547660959759, 
    9.07156680065379, 7.89534013885515), `300` = c(6.61749642892434, 
    9.11432897723339, 7.93934226387229), `301` = c(6.53844576195142, 
    9.02106532505258, 7.81099322303518), `302` = c(6.52307271915732, 
    9.0004042192389, 7.77833574374253), `303` = c(6.64113451411503, 
    9.10710661493899, 7.85809786674559), `304` = c(6.50556641880541, 
    8.96563774045251, 7.70746185521372), `305` = c(6.59874554582051, 
    9.05711394833278, 7.79370468600503), `306` = c(6.76949402827521, 
    9.23740568961713, 7.9899304306054), `307` = c(6.86815993675659, 
    9.32678043213619, 8.05863748964317), `308` = c(6.92811413186287, 
    9.37661433563167, 8.08826108927545), `309` = c(6.79984670819529, 
    9.27786880306163, 8.05194155070315), `310` = c(6.75093984852109, 
    9.22446083346864, 7.9893780085978), `311` = c(6.66632164078636, 
    9.13433665891962, 7.88908122221876), `312` = c(6.63169347873578, 
    9.12197418418377, 7.92907810288665), `313` = c(6.39535546937841, 
    8.8908791745551, 7.71674680370847), `314` = c(6.36390388803788, 
    8.86574495676558, 7.71038143337268), `315` = c(6.36828039339618, 
    8.87344178151668, 7.7281717168546), `316` = c(3.84651667233353, 
    1.80540917848256, 2.06377581477879), `317` = c(3.83006324177741, 
    1.71809974811489, 2.10552869603317), `318` = c(3.81390720921326, 
    1.60306607769455, 2.17921996527599), `319` = c(2.64470453890738, 
    4.96768589318712, 3.68870230077813), `320` = c(2.99243582274812, 
    5.33989024536515, 4.05716522323107), `321` = c(4.9478296392284, 
    7.15429540071734, 5.63931860340141), `322` = c(3.44428416277911, 
    5.8486628413022, 4.60600948137437), `323` = c(3.50850728885876, 
    5.93635183062135, 4.72465608990346), `324` = c(3.61898414636416, 
    6.03760955862433, 4.80552580745364), `325` = c(4.94910274149059, 
    7.16647405925714, 5.66005513241291), `326` = c(4.95796103017858, 
    7.18617841984907, 5.68824052783798), `327` = c(4.23987478837982, 
    6.64423418855889, 5.36094772573095), `328` = c(4.16584423503063, 
    6.58584780550839, 5.32882988368291), `329` = c(4.09212306974758, 
    6.51003053906947, 5.25313266156804), `330` = c(5.07027006968043, 
    7.19084758272565, 5.61108424910497), `331` = c(1.21071686915532, 
    2.32629265588457, 1.07260220188112), `332` = c(1.76157670498754, 
    3.08632121680045, 1.48890075988989), `333` = c(1.73958813121876, 
    3.22023358245386, 1.66441892613216), `334` = c(2.40594656864329, 
    4.68544606909985, 3.38966449091809), `335` = c(2.7254469995444, 
    5.05566667698429, 3.77667106307618), `336` = c(3.07362729814238, 
    5.42847061626994, 4.14795599040178), `337` = c(3.12073939801283, 
    5.47782558273336, 4.19644962697047), `338` = c(3.7481067685189, 
    6.1603235647464, 4.91178722545554), `339` = c(4.0801929576788, 
    6.4969295198125, 5.23881262822501), `340` = c(4.27180108963557, 
    6.60661822706147, 5.23553636452295), `341` = c(5.40741606651064, 
    7.94031137869232, 6.93938432173873), `342` = c(5.40600095611935, 
    7.93576759621346, 6.91459713271997), `343` = c(5.31508767448967, 
    7.81336657210858, 6.67306672488119), `344` = c(5.27451314615617, 
    7.76334674775457, 6.59902171404753), `345` = c(5.22620564139098, 
    7.69910531983853, 6.49902771472678), `346` = c(5.14139820555866, 
    7.59192000275965, 6.34991136309686)
```

In another dataset i have the distance of each nest compared to every other nest.

[image]

```
structure(list(Nestnumber = c("1", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28"
), `23` = c(1.205884184543, 0.318762436378869, 0.367615658508239, 
0.174425803896455, 0.499024772840494, 0.306540196937531), `24` = c("1.1825681475468486", 
"0", "0.13313273435948481", "0.35126537490899756", "0.42441158101057197", 
"0.38773959465028951"), `25` = c(1.05402572134758, 0.133132734359485, 
0, 0.332796848188286, 0.300298370552488, 0.319906205112191), 
    `26` = c(1.03313125157898, 0.351265374908998, 0.332796848188286, 
    0, 0.354498813853459, 0.136925532736399), `27` = c(0.759356311504655, 
    0.424411581010572, 0.300298370552488, 0.354498813853459, 
    9.49352979660034e-05, 0.231868518812083), `28` = c(0.899499609805578, 
    0.38773959465029, 0.319906205112191, 0.136925532736399, 0.231868518812083, 
    0), `29` = c(0.836276747378436, 0.357670735257978, 0.224679099844401, 
    0.401424665895377, 0.124975892637141, 0.306605622769981), 
    `30` = c(0.850751304931217, 0.427818449660403, 0.30381207347973, 
    0.548190805915312, 0.259776387829551, 0.458870938827217), 
    `31` = c(1.01257285756145, 0.212765019875877, 0.0979660978949608, 
    0.412515237816412, 0.285543298576454, 0.372992171654823), 
    `32` = c("1.0327688497916105", "0.33363713512916338", "0.25022711521451413", 
    "0.57011206718331175", "0.38312473052415341", "0.5205606595451564"
    ), `33` = c(0.660254065141036, 0.529477417842921, 0.397743879696547, 
    0.489760262286543, 0.136141553521787, 0.362871148606874), 
    `34` = c(1.55901924650831, 2.52777832276436, 2.42819462748472, 
    2.23221001243478, 2.14316803503825, 2.1468319856475), `35` = c(1.8533107457964, 
    2.78302948508571, 2.68897991143908, 2.4751415284984, 2.41027435404132, 
    2.39808117012818), `36` = c(1.77348817463255, 2.71559187496798, 
    2.61986041590132, 2.41116133327917, 2.33915500030213, 2.33163863839339
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I've managed to get a list of all nests that are within 500 meter of a trial per trial using the `which` funciton, but i don't know how i can then compare the distances between those nests per trial.

```
k=data.frame(which(trialomit<=0.5,arr.ind=T))
j=k[order(k$row),]
```

results in a list all columns (corresponding to a nest) for each row(corresponding to a trial) that are within 0.5(500 meters).

j=data.frame(k[order(k$row),])

> j

```
    row col
31    1  24
33    1  25
35    1  26
36    1  27
38    1  28
40    1  29
41    1  31
42    1  34
240   1 172
241   1 173
45    2  37
46    2  38
48    2  39
49    2  40
51    2  41
52    2  42
203   2 119
248   2 179
70    3  52
74    3  54
77    3  55
80    3  56
85    3  57
89    3  58
93    3  59
96    3  60
100   3  61
104   3  62
108   3  63
115   3  65
119   3  66
123   3  67
```

But i don't know how i can run a code that then takes this list and per "row" checks whether there is a difference of 0.1(100 meter) between any of the "col" nests within the nestxnest data set.

any type of output that looks like:

```
trial | nests within 500m | nests within 200m | (optionally) nests within 500m accounted for 100m seperation
trial1| 10                |   5               |  8
```

Comment: Please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: I hope this is good? my dataset is quite large so i can't get all of the rows and columns in there